# Issue with OV2640 camera and ESP32

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32

I have an OV2640 camera I am trying to integrate with a ESP32_Devkitc_v4 chip and having troubles with the camera initialization. I am not sure I have all the connections correct and have updated the KConfig file to enable this camera.

Pinouts:

```
Camera => ESP32
CS     => D0
MOSI   => 23
MISO   => 19
SCK    => 18
SDA    => D2
SLC    => D1
```

It also needs this: Enable PSRAM on `menuconfig` or type it directly on `sdkconfig`.

But for the life of me I cannot find the 'menuconfig' in the VSCode IDE.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've installed ESP IDF according to the [installation manual](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/) you open a terminal window, go to the root directory of your source project, activate the ESP IDF environment and run the `idf.py` with argument `menuconfig`. Sample for Linux/Mac users:

```
$ cd your_project_folder
$ . $HOME/esp/esp-idf/export.sh
$ idf.py menuconfig
```

I doubt if this has been integrated with VSCode.

Comment: I still have not gotten this to work, but have not been able to spend much time on it. The fact that I am using VSCode is complicating everything like crazy.

Comment: This has nothing to do with VSCode. Open your terminal/console application and follow instructions.